# Помогите, пожалуйста. Уже жду неделю. Python

Tags: python

```
def firi(param1, param2, func, check):     
    if isinstance(param1, int) and isinstance(param2, int):     
        # Если оба параметра - числа     
        for i in range(param1, param2):     
            if eval(str(check)):     
                exec(str(func))     
    else:     
        if isinstance(param1, int):     
            # Если первый параметр - число, а второй - промежуток для цикла     
            for i in range(param2):     
                if eval(str(check)):     
                    exec(str(func))     
    else:     
            # Если первый параметр - переменная, а второй - число     
            if eval(str(check)):     
                exec(str(func))    
j=5     
firi(j, 10, 'print(j)', 2+2==4)
```

Сейчас выводит 5 пятёрок, а может кто помочь, чтобы выводило от 5 до 9? Но, чтобы осталась такая запись:
`firi(j, 10, 'print(j)', 2+2==4)`

Comment: Подскажите, а что функция вообще должна делать? Чего вы ждёте? Может, отыщем вариант лаконичнее)

Comment: функция должна работать как
for j in range(5,10):
    if 2+2==4:
        print(j)

Comment: Ну и поменяйте i на j: `for j in range(param1, param2):`

Comment: 3-й и 4-й аргументы - это то, что должна выполнить функция и условие, которое если правдиво, то выполняет 3-й аргумент.

Comment: i поменять на j нельзя, т.к. я могу вставить любую переменную в firi(), например firi(a, 10, 'print(a)', 2+2==4)

Comment: оформите вопрос как полагается - в заголовке краткая суть вопроса, в теле - сама задача.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте в качестве параметра `func` анонимную функцию `lambda`, тогда и `exec` не нужен:

```py
def firi(param1, param2, func, check):     
    ...
        for i in range(param1, param2):     
            if eval(str(check)):     
                func(i)  
...
firi(j, 10, lambda x: print(x), 2+2==4)
```

Да и `check` у вас сейчас просто `True`, я бы его тоже на какую-нибудь `lambda` поменял.

Comment: Но есть проблемка. Можно написать firi(1, 10, lambda x: print(x), 2+2==4), и выведет числа от 1 до 9, хотя следовало бы вывести 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13, т.к. переменной x мы задали значение 5

Comment: и exec и eval я использую для того, чтобы ниписание функции firi() было максимально коротким

Answer (score 0):

Ваш комментарий очень прояснил ситуацию. Нельзя ли обойтись таким вариантом?

```
def foo(a, b, func, check): 
    for j in range(a, b): 
        if check: 
            exec(func)
            
            
foo(5, 10, 'print(j)', 2 + 2 == 4)
```

Единственный минус, который на данный момент я вижу, это то, что имя переменной `j` должно совпадать в `print(j)` и цикле `for`

P.S. exec нужно использовать аккуратно, и не применять его к коду, который приходит откуда-то извне

Comment: В том то и дело, надо, чтобы могли быть любые переменные